# Unitary equivalent stabilizer codes

Tags: stabilizer-code, clifford-group, stabilizer-state

The trivial stabilizer code is defined by $$T=\{|0\rangle^{\otimes(n-k)}\otimes|\Psi\rangle:|\Psi\rangle\in(\mathbb{C}^{2})^{k}\}\tag{1}$$ which is stabilized by the Pauli operators $Z_1, ...., Z_{n-k}$.

How can we prove Claim 2 on page 2 of this [note](https://web.mit.edu/8.371/www/lectures/lect06.pdf)?

It seems we need to apply the discussion on page 4, but how?
In other words, if $g_1,...,g_{n-k}$ are the stabilizer generators of code $S$, we need to find a unitary operator $u$ such that $ug_iu^{\dagger}=Z_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: $u$ is just the "encoder". To go from a set of stabilizers to encoder is not trivial but is well understood...it should be described in many places; look for "encoding circuit" or variations of that.

Comment: To uniquely define such a Clifford unitary $u$, you have to pick a logical basis for your code. Then, you can read off the binary/symplectic representation of $u$ and use that in standard compilation methods. See also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9534/stabilizer-circuit-synthesis-via-clifford-gates/15665#15665

Comment: Thank you very much!